# Issue when creating staging for Wordpress multisite with sub-domains

Tags: multisite

We have currently a production website that is a Wordpress Multisite with 2 separate URLs, however, it uses the same base code, and I believe there is a single database that feeds both websites.

So basically, a change in the base code affects both websites, but both websites have to be updated in order to not break anything.

The structure is:

```
abc.com - main website 
xyz.dev - other subsites
```

abc and xyz have the same base code, templates, functions and others.

We are trying to move it to a UAT server because we need to make major changes and we want to replicate the production environment in the UAT server, so that we can make the changes and then move it back the production, but the problem we are facing with the plugins we used is that the main website is properly migrated and URL is updated, but the 2nd website stays pointing to production URL.

UAT server structure we are trying to implement:

```
uat.com/abc/ 
uat.com/xyz/
```

We tried to use the following plugins:

WP Vivid backup
Updraft Plus
But we are struggling with all of them and can't seem to find a solution. What approach would you recommend for this specific case?